# Envelope Enrichment?

Tags: planetary-formation, terminology

While I was researching about planet formation, I repeatedly came across the term *envelope enrichment*. What does this mean?

I searched it up and looked at many websites, but no helpful definitions showed.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm pretty sure "enrichment" refers to the presence/production of heavy elements (i.e., metals) in the planet's atmosphere

Comment: It's my cynical friday feeling coming through, but it sounds awfully like when politicians get an envelope full of money "anonymously". :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the accretion phase of a planet, along with the H/He gas, there are dust particles or heavy elements in the gas phase accreted into the outer shell of a planet (or THE planet in the case of gas giants).
Should the fraction of this heavy element X in relation to H/He, i.e. the number $\rm [X/H]$ increase through this process, we speak of enrichment.  If it decreases, we speak of depletion.

However, and absolute value of $\rm [X/H]$ might not be indicative of interesting physics. Instead, usually $\rm [X/H]$ is compared to a standard value, e.g. that of the solar atmosphere $\rm [X/H]_{\odot}$. This is because the primordial nebula will have had some base number of heavy elements in it, and only having *more* heavy elements than that base-line value will count as enriched.
I.e. if your element has abundance X with $\rm [X/H]-\rm [X/H]_{\odot}=0$, is has neither enriched nor depleted abundance, but *solar* abundance. If it has $\rm [X/H]-\rm [X/H]_{\odot}>0$ it is *enriched relative to the solar value*.

So those are two slightly different meanings of enrichment, which one is in use depends on the text you are reading.